# Shift data from text Area(string) to inputs type number

Tags: javascript

I have a problem because I want to transfer values ​​from `TextArea` where they have been pasted with Office excel and they are separated by line breaker exactly like and Office Excel. To the rest of inputs with a numeric type.
So we have one Text area and 50 inputs type numbers[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O2uL.jpg)

here is my code below but I stuck right now and need some help,directions or example.
Thanks

```
// btn
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn--shift");
// text Area
let inputInArea = document.querySelector(".btn--input");

// test first input
let textInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
var numbers = [];
btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let inputInAreaValue = inputInArea.value;
    let parsedStringToNumber = parseInt(inputInAreaValue);

    numbers.push(parsedStringToNumber);
    console.log(numbers);
    // FIXME:
    textInput[0].value = parsedStringToNumber;
    textInput.forEach(function(single) {
        single.value = parsedStringToNumber;
    });
    console.log(inputInAreaValue);
    // console.log(textInput[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a combination of [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the value of your `textarea` for that :

- `textareaVal.split('\n')` will split your `textarea` value for every `newline`
- `.filter(e => e != '')` will remove the empty values from your array

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click',function(){
  let textareaVal = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  let values = textareaVal.split('\n').filter(e => e != '');
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="txt">222
333

444

555
</textarea>

<button id="test">Test !</button>
```